# How to flip the position of points created using Graphics or Graphics2D relative to the center point

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Hello I'm working on graphics using Java Swing

I want to take the points on the jpanel and then flip them up and down at the same time based on the jpanel center point.

I looked for a way to rotate the jpanel or flip it upside down, but I could only see the data associated with the img file.

If there is no other way, should I use the transformation matrix to move all the points one by one?

Comment: Hi @Coolluck, your question seems to be unclear, can you explain what you have did. If there is any fiddle/ code snippets will be helpful to answer your question. Look in to How to Ask -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: *"should I use the transformation matrix to move all the points one by one?"* Yes. It's not that hard. Set the transform at the beginning of `paintComponent(..)` and then paint as you normally would. Don't forget to reset the transform after the painting is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Graphics2D and AffineTransform.

Here's Code Example.

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // Panel Size = 400 X 400
        g.drawLine(200, 0, 200, 400); // Draw Y Axis
        g.drawLine(0, 200, 400, 200); // Draw X Axis

        // Create Transform
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.translate(200, 200); // Move Center Form (0, 0) To JPanel Center (200, 200)

        // Change Transform - Test One Line At Once For Study :) 
        //at.translate(-200, 0); // Move Center
        //at.rotate(Math.toRadians(90)); // Rotate
        //at.scale(1, -1); // Scale, But Use For Flip

        // Set Transform To Graphics2D
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setTransform(at);

        // Draw Rectangle By Graphics2D
        g2d.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    }
```

Comment: If you're going to apply a transform to the graphics context you should use `g.create()` and then dispose of it when your done.  Otherwise the change will persist to the next use of that context.

Comment: I was able to use at.scale(1.-1) that way. Thank you for your kind explanation ^^.
after flip it up down or left right, I have to move it back to the original position so that I can see it from the jpanel.